# Cannot call value of non function type error in RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, reactive

Hello i am quite newbie in RxSwift and Swift.

I am getting following error
"Cannot call value of non function type ((ResponseTestData) -> Swift.Void)?"

My first question is why i am getting this error when i call onResult(result!) ???

```
func getTestList(perPage : String, pageNum : String, onResult: ((ResponseTestData) -> Swift.Void)? = nil, onFail: ((Error) -> Swift.Void)? = nil, disposeBag : DisposeBag)
{
    let tmpRx : RxManager
    tmpRx = RxManager()

    tmpRx.fetchTestData(perPage : perPage, pageNum : pageNum)
        .debug()
        .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
        .subscribeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
        .subscribe(
            onNext:
            {
                (result : ResponseTestData)->() in
                onResult(result!)
                print(result.result!)
            },
            onError:
            {
                _ in
                print("")
            },
            onCompleted:
            {
                print("")
            }

        )
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `onResult` is an Optional, so you need to use optional chaining. Therefore, `onResult(result!)` becomes `onResult?(result!)`

Second, if your `fetchTestData` returns an `Observable<ResponseTestData>`, then you need to remove the `!` from `result`.

So I would expect it to look like this:

```
.subscribe(onNext: { (result : ResponseTestData) -> Void in
        onResult?(result)
        print(result)
},
```